# Fluent Nhibernate - HasMany - child objects not saved

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a ReportRequest object defined as:

```
public class ReportRequest
{
    public virtual Int32? Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<ReportClient> ReportClients{get;set;}
}
```

and ReportClient is defined as:

```
public class ReportClient
{
    public virtual int? Id { get; set; }

    public virtual long? ClientId { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<ReportClient> ChildClients { get; set; }
}
```

mapping for ReportClient:

```
public class ReportClientMap : ClassMap<ReportClient>
{
    public ReportClientMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).UnsavedValue(null).GeneratedBy.Native();
        Map(x => x.ClientId);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.EmailAddress).Length(255);
        HasMany<ReportClient>(x => x.ChildClients)
            .KeyColumn("ParentId")
            .KeyNullable()
            .AsBag()
            .Inverse()
            .ForeignKeyConstraintName("FK_ReportClient_ParentId");
    }
}
```

ChildClients are required to be saved as ReportClient but with ParentId being set.

Though ReportRequest and ReportClients are being saved fine, but the issue I am facing is ReportClient.ChildClients are not being saved.

I am not even getting any error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set cascade to save-update for ChildClients property mapping:

```
  HasMany<ReportClient>(x => x.ChildClients)
        .KeyColumn("ParentId")
        .KeyNullable()
        .AsBag()
        .Inverse()
        .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
        .ForeignKeyConstraintName("FK_ReportClient_ParentId");
```

Comment: Thank you! Though child client is being saved now, but with ParentId=NULL. What changes I could make to set the ParentId too?

Comment: In order to get the ParentId to not be null, I believe you'd need to have a Parent property on the ReportClient, in order to point it to it's parent ReportClient. Then, be sure to set the Parent when you add it to a child collection.

Comment: removed Inverse() to sort out above issue.